zsh case-insensitive completion match not working
Problem
I've recently made some changes to my terminal development tools. Everything has been working as expected, except for case-insensitive match completion, which before it would match completions case-insensitive and from any direction.

Setup

OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Shell: zsh
Terminal: Wezterm
Prompt: Starship
Plugin Manager: zinit


Code
Sample of .zshrc config file related to completions.
# zsh plugins
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions
zinit light Aloxaf/fzf-tab

# Load zsh-completions
autoload -U compinit && compinit

# Completion styling
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
setopt MENU_COMPLETE
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
zstyle ':completion:*' meno no


I've seen some other issues related to this and went through zsh documentation but still didn't figure out... If anyone have any hint
about it, if there's any mistake in the config file or anything else, i would be grateful... 

I tried testing this using your configurations in .zshrc file and after some debugging, I found out that the issue was because of your matcher-list expression. Here's my correction to your config after your zsh plugins.
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'

setopt MENU_COMPLETE
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
zstyle ':completion:*' meno no

Hopefully this helps you !

I thought that could be the problem, so before i even post, i tried some other combinations for matcher-list... Unfortunately, none of it worked. I tried your suggestion, tried 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{A-Z}={a-z}', but none seems to work properly. But i do appreciate the effort to help :)

@LucasNG. Sorry to hear that :(
Is it possible that the zinit manager could be the reason for this?

I do believe so, since before this problem, i used oh-my-zsh for plugin manager and this wasn't a problem... But i still prefer to keep with zinit and starship. I'll also start an issue on zinit repo to see if there's a work around...
